# add 15 minutes in a YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format variable

Tags: python

I have a variable holding information about time (not current time) in the YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format.

I have a starting point and a finish point. Lets say '20210419000100' and '20210419130100'. Thats 13 hours from start to finish.

I want to save a string of this time for every 15 mins. ie we start at '20210419000100' and 15 mins later it will be '20210419001600'.

Obviously its not always +1500. I know its a long shot, but is there a tool for that or how could i do that in a generic way that would work with any starting point I would choose? It could be done only in HHMMSS format if its easier but if possible I would like the year/month/day to change, too.

I am more interested in a python solution.

Comment: What is your platform (windows / linux /macos)

Comment: You mean is there a module for manipulating `datetime`s?

Comment: Because `datetime.strptime` is platform dependant

Comment: platform is Ubuntu but I didnt think its important. i will look into ```datetime.strptime```. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[python-dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) to the rescue!

```
from dateutil import parser, relativedelta

START_DATE = '20210419000100'
END_DATE = '20210419130100'

start = parser.parse(START_DATE)
end = parser.parse(END_DATE)

while start < end:
    print(start.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
    start += relativedelta.relativedelta(minutes=15)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to install other dependencies, you can use python's standard `datetime` module

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

time_str = '20210419000100'
time_obj = datetime.strptime(time_str, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

print(time_obj)
# 2021-04-19 00:01:00


# If you want to add hours or minutes
def seconds(h = 0, m = 0, s = 0):
    return h * 3600 + m * 60 + s

time_obj += timedelta(0, seconds(m=15)) # days, seconds

print(time_obj)
# 2021-04-19 00:16:00

# In case you want to convert it back
new_time_str = time_obj.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

print(new_time_str)
# 20210419001600
```